# Python attributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am using Python3 in Windows 7 and I installed pyserial 3.3. I create a file named serial.py with these line codes:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=0)
ser.write(b'mymessage')
```

it will show this error message:

```
attributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

for all other samples in their [documentation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) it's same, and I could not use any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hah!
the problem was my filename. I was using same file name with my python package!
I changed my filename from `serial.py` to `test.py` and it start working.